# jquery dataTable cannot break text if it is a URL

Tags: jquery, css

I am working with a password keeper website. In the project, it shows a jquery dataTable which contain website, username, password, and note. However, the website column will show the URL as a line that the column width will be too large if the URL is too long..

But the funny thing is the note column of the table will break text if too long.

for example:

```
URL(will not break): http://www.text.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/too_long_cannot_show/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Username:Username
Password:Password
Note(will break which depend on window's width): I am note.I am note.I am note.I am note.I am note.I am note.I am note.I am note.*100
```

I have tried:

```
create a div to contain the table, then set its max-width:1000px ==> fail
override the dataTable class, set its max-width:1000px ==> fail
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with dataTables. Your note text contains white spaces while URL does not contain any of them (pure HTML/CSS things).

Use `word-break: break-all;` for places where word wrap does not break words meanings (like URL)

```css
.auto-break {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-break">http://www.text.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/too_long_cannot_show/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```